# Operand should contain 1 column(s) insert

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I was looking for a solution to this problem but I can't find it. I tried everything they say in the forums but nothing works for me

```
public boolean ingresarEntrada(String pl, String fech, String hora,String tipo){

    ConexionBD sql=new ConexionBD();
    Connection cn = sql.Conectar();



    String query= "insert into datos(serie, placa, fecha, hora_entrada, hora_salida, tipo, transcurrido, total)"
            + "values((NULL, '"+pl+"', '"+fech+"', '"+hora+"', '', '"+tipo+"', '', ''))"; 


    String mensaje="Datos ingresados correctamente";
    try {


        sql.stmt.executeUpdate(query);


    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: The Log would be super helpful here

Comment: A space is missing after `total)`

Comment: Also, big suggestions, use 'PreparedStatement' in SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra set of parenthesis inside of values. Try:

```
values(NULL, '"+pl+"', ...
```

instead.